# extjs change text font size in the htmleditor

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've almost completed this issue: i surround selected text in  with font-size and then send it bak to the textarea.

**But spans are added all the time**. I think i need to know if i have my span already in the selection.. and just *change font-size*... help please

See fiddle: combobox for the size is at the right corner

http://jsfiddle.net/DCGRg/70/

look there over this code:

```
//get selection content
        content = selection.extractContents();
        //create span and wrap it around selection
        fontEl = document.createElement ("span")
        fontEl.style.fontSize=font_size+'px'
        fontEl.appendChild(content);
        mod_text = fontEl.outerHTML
        old_text=fontEl.innerHTML
        selection.insertNode(fontEl);
        //END----------------------------
        //alert(fontEl.firstChild.nodeName)
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any spans added on your fiddle, by typing text, selecting it and clicking the font size buttons

Comment: I'm not seeing it either. Only seeing the creation of <font> tags.

Comment: no, it's not buttons, it's combobox to the right of the toolbar, in which u have to select font!